# How do I use the BLAS library provided by MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, blas

I have noticed that MATLAB provides the BLAS and LAPACK headers among others:

```
$ ls ${MATLAB_DIR}/extern/include/
blas.h            engine.h    lapack.h           mat.h            mclmcr.h      mex.h           mwutil.h
blascompat32.h    fintrf.h    libmatlbm.mlib     matrix.h         mclmcrrt.h    mwdebug.h       tmwtypes.h
emlrt.h           io64.h      libmatlbmx.mlib    mclcppclass.h    mcr.h         mwservices.h
```

I would like to use them for my compiled code, so I tried to compile the following:

**ex_blas.c**

```
#include <blas.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

with the following command:

```
$ mex ex_blas.c
```

But this returns an error:

```
In file included from ex_blas.c:1:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/extern/include/blas.h:51: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/extern/include/blas.h:62: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/extern/include/blas.h:77: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/extern/include/blas.h:92: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/extern/include/blas.h:103: error: syntax error before ‘ptrdiff_t’
/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/extern/include/blas.h:122: error: syntax error before ‘ptrdiff_t’
```

Is the `blas.h` provided by MATLAB usable by a 3rd party application outside of MATLAB? If yes, what is causing the error above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will completely resolve your problems, but you may also have to include [`stddef.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstddef/) since that is where the `ptrdiff_t` type is defined.