# MATLAB (2013b) "doc" cannot load libxul.so from Java on Linux system

Tags: linux, matlab, xul

After successful installation of MATLAB R2013b on openSUSE 13.1 64bit I have got the following error message when I try to open MATLAB Help via "doc" command (see attached message).

MATLAB Help window always shows corrupted formatting and/or rendering of the text content.

```
>> doc
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/MATLAB/R2013b/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/MATLAB/R2013b/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/MATLAB/R2013b/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/MATLAB/R2013b/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/MATLAB/R2013b/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
MEvent. CASE!
MEvent. CASE!
MEvent. CASE!
MEvent. CASE!
MEvent. CASE!
MEvent. CASE!
>>
```

Comment: Relevant link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268293/matlab-error-cannot-open-with-static-tls

Answer (score 1):

this is Linux specific bug of Matlab R2012b and higher ([official Mathworks bug report](http://www.mathworks.de/support/bugreports/961964))

You could try to execute `doc` one you startup Matlab and can hope that at this point the necessary libraries can be loaded.

**EDIT:** quoting from the Mathworks bug report:

```
On Linux machines, when performing linear algebra operations such as matrix multiplications, MATLAB could return the following error:

>> b = ones(10)*ones(10);
Error using *
BLAS loading error:
dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS

Any subsequent linear algebra operations will return the same error. You must restart MATLAB in order to perform further linear algebra operations.

Workaround

This issue has to do with the loading order of MATLAB's linear algebra library. To work around this issue, load the linear algebra library early in a MATLAB session, by performing a linear algebra operation immediately after MATLAB starts. For example, perform a matrix multiplication:

>> ones(10)*ones(10);

You can also add the above command to your startup.m file to make MATLAB run it at startup.
```

Comment: This is definitely not linux specific bug!!! Under Debian (6 and 7), Ubuntu 12.04, etc. is everything OK. Moreover I have absolutely no problem with linear algebra functions, so TMW bug is not relevant to this problem.

Comment: @michal the bug doesn't necessarily show up immediately on all distributions but I've seen it myself on Ubuntu 12.04. Also the official Mathworks bug states that this happens on Linux systems. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem in MATLAB 2014a, but the mathworks support could help me. Their solution was to run

```
webutils.htmlrenderer('basic');
```

in the command window. See [Bug 1003952](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1003952).
Even in **MATLAB 2015a** the bug is still present.