# Is there a way to determine thread local storage model used by a library on Linux

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, glibc, thread-local-storage, ldd

Is there a way to query the TLS model of a shared library on Linux? (eg using ldd or some other tool).

I am having a trouble with loading too many libraries with the "initial-exec" model and would like to determine for sure which of the third party libs use this model (so I can free up some slots eg by linking statically).

This results in an error:

```
 dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
```

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268293/matlab-error-cannot-open-with-static-tls).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran into this error myself, and while investigating it, I came on a [mailing list post with this info](http://www.redhat.com/archives/phil-list/2003-February/msg00077.html):

> If you link a shared object containing IE-model access relocs, the object
>   will have the DF_STATIC_TLS flag set.  By the spec, this means that dlopen
>   might refuse to load it.

Looking at `/usr/include/elf.h`, we have:

```
/* Values of `d_un.d_val' in the DT_FLAGS entry.  */
...
#define DF_STATIC_TLS   0x00000010      /* Module uses the static TLS model */
```

So you need to test if `DF_STATIC_TLS` is set in the `DT_FLAGS` entry of the shared library.

To test things, I created a simple piece of code using thread local storage:

```
static __thread int foo;
void set_foo(int new) {
    foo = new;
}
```

I then compiled it twice with the two different thread local storage models:

```
gcc -ftls-model=initial-exec -fPIC -c tls.c  -o tls-initial-exec.o
gcc -shared tls-initial-exec.o -o tls-initial-exec.so

gcc -ftls-model=global-dynamic -fPIC -c tls.c  -o tls-global-dynamic.o
gcc -shared tls-global-dynamic.o -o tls-global-dynamic.so
```

And sure enough, I can see a difference between the two libraries using `readelf`:

```
$ readelf --dynamic tls-initial-exec.so

Dynamic section at offset 0xe00 contains 25 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
...
 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              STATIC_TLS
```

The `tls-global-dynamic.so` version did not have a `DT_FLAGS` entry, presumably because it didn't have any flags set.  So it should be fairly easy to create a script using `readelf` and `grep` to find affected libraries.

Comment: Thanks very much! Great answer. I also found `readelf -l library | grep TLS` useful. This indicates if there is any thread loca storage at all. It turns out anything with TLS also uses a DTV slot (and so can block later STATIC_TLS objects from loading), but if you load the STATIC_TLS objects first, the non-intial-exec ones use another method and don't take a slot.

Comment: @robince Thank you **so** much for this comment (+1).  I could not figure out why loading order mattered

Comment: As I recently found out, aarch64 binaries don't have `STATIC_TLS` in `FLAGS` even if static TLS is used.
The best I found is to look for relocation entries in `readelf -a -W library | grep R_AARCH64_TLS_TPREL64` output. If there are any, it indicates static TLS binary.
The equivalent for x86_64 is `R_X86_64_TPOFF64`.