# Compiling shared library with Clang for mex -> cannot load any more object with static TLS

Tags: c++, matlab, clang, mex

I have a bunch of C++ code that I'd like to call from Matlab. I compile the code into a shared library, make a small mex interface, and compile that with mex while linking to the .so.

Basically, I have a CMake file with

```
add_library(mylibrary SHARED <dependencies>)
```

which i compile with

```
(optionally export CXX=clang++); cmake ..; make
```

and call mex with

```
mex -lmylibrary [...]
```

This works fine if I compile the original code with g++. If I try to use clang++ (exact same flags etc), however, the mex compilation still runs fine but upon trying to call the function in matlab I get the error

```
Invalid MEX-file '<path_to_file>.mexa64': dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
```

This isn't a huge issue obviously because I can just use g++, but I'd prefer to use clang if possible because the compilation is quite a bit faster and the warnings/errors are nicer.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19268293/2778484

Comment: what's used in your mex script to link libraries, clang or g++?

Comment: @chappjc thanks, seems like a different problem though.

Comment: @user3528438 g++. i wasn't aware that shared libraries are compiler-dependent like that, is that true?