# Python import fails with "dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS"

Tags: python, cython, dlopen, pycaffe

I have written a multi-threaded module called `fast_nn` in `Cython` and compiled it with the following `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize([
        Extension("fast_nn", ["fast_nn.pyx"], language = 'c++', extra_compile_args = ['-O3', '-fopenmp'], extra_link_args = ['-fopenmp'], include_dirs = [numpy.get_include()])
    ])
)
```

In addition, I use the python bindings of the `caffe` framework.

If I use my module alone or `pycaffe` alone, everything is fine. However, the following combination is problematic:

```
import caffe.io
import fast_nn
```

On one machine, it does not lead to any problems. On another machine, I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import fast_nn
ImportError: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
```

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268293/matlab-error-cannot-open-with-static-tls) I understand that too many libraries with initial-exec static TLS have been loaded dynamically. But what can I do to work around this problem? Is there some way to compile my module with static TLS disabled or a better solution?

However, the output of `readelf -a fast_nn.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep TLS` does not show any TLS symbols in my library. But some dependent libraries contain such symbols.

---

### Solutions tried so far

Changing the order of the two imports (i.e., importing `caffe` after my `cython` module) solves the problem. However, since my actual real-world case is much more complex and both modules are imported indirectly from other imports, I cannot change the order of imports.

Similarly, exporting the path of my compiled module library to `LD_PRELOAD` has the same effect, but is not an elegant solution either.